# recycler поверх всего

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, coordinator-layout

Есть разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Обернул в CoordinatorLayout но при открытии NavigationDrawer'a recycler находится поверх всех окон, и даже при переходе в другой фрагмент приложения, сверху данный recycler.

Answer (score 1):

1. В DrawerLayout можно помещать только два (три, если предполагаются меню с 2 сторон) элемента разметки.
2. Один из них должен быть левым и/или правым меню, а другой - контент
3. Чтобы сделать ту разметку, которую вы хотите вам нужно:

   1. Обернуть AppBarLayout и RecyclerView в CoordinatorLayout
   2. Добавить поведение для RecyclerView так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Т.е. схематически выглядеть разметка итоговая должна так:

```
DrawerLayout 
    CoordinatorLayout
        AppBarLayout
        RecyclerView
    NavigationView
```

Comment: Добавил примерно следующим образом, но всё равно некорректно(

Comment: @Inkognito, я рассписал корректное решение. У меня и у всех оно работает. Вы где-то ошиблись. Но вы не дополнили вопрос новой информацией и нельзя без неё угадать где вы ошиблись

Comment: Я наверное и в правду что то не так делаю, но вроде всё как вы сказали. вопрос дополнил.

Comment: @Inkognito, вы забыли про пункт 3.2